# Javascript widget inspired by iPhone UITableView?

Tags: javascript, iphone

Cocoa Touch's UITableView allows a user to scroll through large numbers of data rows with good performance because it recycles table rows. Rather than create a GUI element for every single data row, a limited number of table rows is created, and simply updated with the relevant data as the user scrolls, giving the illusion of navigating up and down a very large number of table rows.

Has anyone seen this done in javascript? Is there a plugin available anywhere that will do this for me?

Comment: Elliot's response should be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

infinity.js works well. It will dynamically load 'pages' behind the scenes giving you the appearance that the list has been fully loaded.

More information can be found on their Github page - https://github.com/airbnb/infinity

Additionally, I've forked the project updating it to work with Zepto. I also set it up to use any scrollable div (set up with overflow: scoll) with the class 'scrollable' - https://github.com/elliotcw/infinity

I should add that I made these changes as this is great for large lists on mobile devices, which slow down when you have to many complex elements on the page.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this as well, and infinityjs [1] doesn't seem to quite mimic the same interface as UITableView. And it was a problem for my scenario that infinityjs required that the element containing the list items already be added to the DOM.

MegaList [2] came closest to what I wanted. Andrew (author) has done a great job of designing it for mobile first, with touch support etc. One caveat for me was that it appears to assume a strict selection list model and does a little bit more than I'd like a list component to do (e.g. binding to resize events and trying to handle that automatically).

So I started writing a barebones list component, also modeled after the iOS UITableView. It's a work in progress and I'm putting in just what I need. Sources are here https://github.com/shyam-habarakada/js-virtual-list-view. I'm putting in just what I need as I go, and contributors are needed :-)

[1] http://airbnb.github.io/infinity/

[3] https://github.com/triceam/MegaList

Answer (score 0):

Actually the algorithm is not difficult at all. If you know javascript you should be able to write this. The algorithm only needs the height of a cell and the height of the table.

I only know these two:
Apple's Dashcode javascript Framework has an implementation of a Table. You could take a look and see if that is what you need.
Or Cappuccino Framework which is basically Objective-J but behind the scenes is Javascript.

Comment: Yes, the basics are simple. I'd like scroll wheel support too, don't know how much work that's going to be. And I'll have to handle animating the cells as they pass in and out of view, which, while not hard, will take me a few hours at least.

Answer (score 0):

[Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/) does exactly that.

It's small and works with any tag (table, lists, divs)