# I have a couple thousand javascript objects which I need to display and scroll through. What are my options?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I'm working off of designs which show a scrollable box containing a list of a user's "contacts".

Users may have up to 10,000 contacts.

For now assume that *all* contacts are already in memory, and I'm simply trying to draw them. If you want to comment on the question of how wise it is to load 10k items of data in a browser, please [do it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282907/is-there-a-limit-to-how-much-data-i-should-cache-in-browser-memory).

There are two techniques I've seen for managing a huge list like this inside a scrollable box.

### Just Load Them All

This *seems* to be how gmail approaches displaying contacts. I currently have 2k contacts in gmail. If I click "all contacts", I get a short delay, then the scrollable box at the right begins to fill with contacts. It looks like they're breaking the task into chunks, probably separating the DOM additions into smaller steps and putting those steps into timeouts in order to not freeze the entire interface while the process completes.

**pros:**

- Simple to implement
- Uses native UI elements the way they were designed to be used
- Google does it, it must be ok

**cons**

- Not totally snappy -- there is some delay involved, even on my development machine running Firefox. There will probably be quite a lot of delay for a user running a slower machine running IE6
- I don't know what sort of limits there are in how large I can allow the DOM to grow, but it seems to me there must be *some* limit to how many nodes I can add to it. How will an older browser on an older machine react if I ask it to hold 10k nodes in the DOM?

### Draw As Needed

This seems to be how Yahoo deals with displaying contact lists. The create a scrollable box, put a super-tall, empty placeholder inside it, and draw contacts only when the user scrolls to reveal them.

**pros:**

- DOM nodes are drawn only as needed, so there's very little delay while loading, and much less risk of overloading the browser with too many DOM nodes

**cons:**

- Trickier to implement, and more opportunity for bugs. For example, if I scroll quickly in the yahoo mail contact manager as soon as the page loads, I'm able to get contacts to load *on top of one another*. Of course, bugs can be worked out, but obviously this approach will introduce more bugs.
- There's still the potential to add a huge number of DOM nodes. If the user scrolls slowly through the entire list, every item will get drawn, and we'll still end up with an enormous DOM

Are there other approaches in common use for displaying a huge list? Any more pros or cons with each approach to add? Any experience/problems/success using either of these approaches?

Answer (score 3):

I would chunk up the DOM-writing into handle-able amounts (say, 25 or 50), then draw the chunks on demand. I wouldn't worry about removing the old DOM elements until the amount drawn gets quite large.

I would divide the contacts into chunks, and keep a sort of view buffer alive that changes which chunks are written to the DOM as the user scrolls through the list. That way the total number of dom elements never rises above a certain threshold. Could be fairly tricky to implement, however.

Using this method you can also dynamically modify the size of chunks and the size of the buffer, depending on the browser's performance (dynamic performance optimization), which could help out quite a bit.

It's definitely non-trivial to implement, however.

The bug you see in Yahoo may be due to absolutely positioned elements: if you keep your CSS simple and avoid absolutely/relatively positioning your contact entries, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks warfangle. If I load the chunks linearly (i.e. if I'm going to draw row 200, draw rows 1-199 first), I can avoid the absolute positioning that yahoo does. Don't see how I can position row 200 without 199 before it to push it down if I'm not using abosolute positioning though. By view buffer, are you talking about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258486/javascript-widget-inspired-by-iphone-uitableview

Comment: This same technique outlined in this answer has been implemented in a form of a plugin. [ClusterizeJS](https://clusterize.js.org/)