# Efficiently showing large list in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a javascript library that efficiently loads a giant list by only loading the viewable part of that list and faking the scrollbar?

```
<div id='container'>
  <!-- Empty but height is set to take up space to fake scrollbar -->
  <div id='hidden-before'></div>      

  <!-- Preloaded in case the user scrolls up -->
  <div id='preload-before'></div>

  <!-- User can see this. Height == #container's height -->
  <div id='viewable-section'></div>   

  <!-- Preloaded in case the user scrolls down -->
  <div id='preload-after'></div>

  <!-- Empty but height is set to take up space to fake scrollbar -->
  <div id='hidden-after'></div>       
</div>
```

Google Docs for example does this for large text documents.

Note: What I am looking for is more complex than infinite scroll. Infinite scroll just waits for you to hit the bottom and it will load more data, enlarging the scrollbar. What I'm looking for will make you think all the data has been loaded because the scrollbars are faked. When you hit the bottom, you've actually hit the end of the list I want to show.

Comment: You should consider ways of making your list smaller, are there categories it can be grouped into? Partially loading the list means that in-page search probably won't work, so you are making the user scroll through the list and manually search it rather than type in a search.

Comment: I think Google Docs does that based on *pages*, which have a fixed height. On an HTML list, there's no way to know the height each list item would take, unless you load them into the DOM.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sure but I can also have a fixed height for each list item I want to show.

Comment: Well, then it's doable, but I don't know any library for that. I guess you'll have to code your own solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/)

This plugin does exactly what you ask.

Comment: how to combine this plugin with dynamic loading of rows?

Comment: @SouhaiebBesbes use .append, .prepend or .update methods. See docs

Comment: [Clusterize.js](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/clusterize-js-commercial-license) is under GNU GPL license v3, $25 for the single commercial license, and $110 for the extended commercial license.

Answer (score 4):

It's a technique called "infinite scroll", and multiple libraries support it. If you're using jQuery, take a look at:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

As you know, the idea is to determine "how much" of the dataset the user can current see, and then perform a request for *only* that much, but set the scroll in relation to the size of the entire set. That way, once the user scrolls past a certain point, you can request for the next part of the dataset.

ExtJS also has this as part of their component-based framework. Here's [a grid example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.html).

Comment: As @LarryK said on his now-deleted answer: "Note that you'll need to make changes on your server-side application to support the pagination requests from the client".

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yes, this is good to mention. And, depending on the complexity of your page (e.g. whether or not need dynamic sorting or grouping), this may require _quite a bit_ of server-side modification.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I've updated the question to hopefully convey the difference between what I'm looking for and infinite scroll. Again, Google Docs does what I'm looking for, which you would not be described as infinite scroll.

Comment: @jhchen: Did you look at the grid example of ExtJS? Is that kind of what you're looking for?

Comment: ExtJS's grid is exactly what I'm looking for! Unfortunately it is GPL3 so I can't use it... Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @jhchen: Well, it's not _just_ GPL3 - it also has [commercial options](http://www.sencha.com/store/extjs). But, I assume that you don't want to pay for a huge library like ExtJS. I can't think of a free ready-made option off the top of my head, but you can probably implement it using the jQuery plugin and some custom setup. The way that the ExtJS grid works is fairly simple: there is a `div` that contains the scrollbar, with `overflow-y: scroll`, and it contains an inner `div` whose `height` is set to a computed value based on the data length. Thus, you get the "infinite scrollbar".

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem. The scenario was that I already had a large (~400+ elements) to be displayed in a list, where each element can have it's own view. The creation, layout and painting of the DOM for those elements was slower than I needed when tryign to render the entire list inside a scrolling DIV.

I looked at several solutions.

**InfinityJS** [1] was pretty close to what I wanted except it required that the element containing the list items already be added to the DOM.

**infinite-scroll** [2] by Paul Irish was also interesting, but was solving a specific problem that was different from what I needed to solve.

**MegaList** [3] came closest to what I wanted. Andrew (author) has done a great job of designing it for mobile first, with touch support etc. One caveat for me was that it appears to assume a strict selection list model and does a little bit more than I'd like a list component to do (e.g. binding to resize events and trying to handle that automatically).

So I started writing a barebones list component losely modeled after the iOS UITableView -- and called is the js-virtual-list-view (vlv :-). It's a work in progress and I wouldn't recommend it over the above unless you have similar needs that aren't quite met with those.

Sources are here https://github.com/shyam-habarakada/js-virtual-list-view.

Contributors needed :-)

[1] http://airbnb.github.io/infinity/

[2] http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

[3] https://github.com/triceam/MegaList

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the overflow attribute in css?
Just give your container div a standard width and height like so:

#container { height: 500px; width: 500px; overflow: auto;}

Comment: The point is I don't want to load all the HTML elements because I will have a lot and it will be slow. I just want to load the ones the user will see, and load the others as he/she scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

This post covers your question and presents answers - http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5

Isn't the killer plugin you're after but goes a long way to explaining how you would go about creating it yourself.

UPDATE: There's a new library called infinity.js, more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108015/921259

Answer (score 1):

You can look into using Polymer's `<iron-list>` which actually consumes all the data but it only attaches a handful of nodes to the DOM and handles data binding to display the right content as the user scrolls through.

I've used it before and got very good results with custom lists of 2000+ items (those items being complex custom elements too) scrolling seamlessly.

Though I haven't tried it myself the Polymer team claims it can be easily mixed with other frameworks.

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you will have performance cost when scrolling a large list. Even if you set `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;` to every element that was not visible on the viewport, you will have some lag because every element still being recalculated when you scrolling the list.

To avoid the recalculation, every element should be moved to Virtual DOM so it will never being rendered and some property (like height/width) will default to `0`.

There are some library that can handle the virtual scroll like [Clusterize](https://clusterize.js.org/), [ngx-ui-scroll](https://dhilt.github.io/ngx-ui-scroll/), [hyperlist](https://github.com/tbranyen/hyperlist), etc.

But some of them doesn't support dynamic row height, some of them aren't MIT licensed, and some of them have a little feature for manipulating the content list. So I decided to build a [MVW library](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/ScarletsFrame) that can handle dynamic row height like [this example](https://playcode.io/224164?tabs=model.js&output). And yes, it's able to use `scrollTo(index)` for automatically scroll to the selected index.

The implementation is just like

```html
<div sf-controller="large-list">
  <ul class="sf-virtual-scroll">

    <li sf-repeat-this="x in list">
      {{x.id}}
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
sf.model.for('large-list', function(self){
  self.list = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    self.list.push({id:i});
  }
});
```

You could manipulate the displayed list with the default array function like `push`, `splice`, `pop`.

Or [try it here](https://jsbin.com/luyuhos/edit?html,js,output)