# Sending large html input in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I do have an ajax form that contains a text area in my MVC project. The text area contains html string. I save this html string to database. On controller side, I use "ValidateInput(false)" for my method.

Everything is okay so far. I have no problem with Visual Studio. After I published the project, there occurs an error like the following. If I write a short html to text area, the method runs with no problem. However, if I write a long html string to text area, the page shows no response. I do not get an error or any result message.

I believe this is about IIS configuration since it works great in Visual Studio. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: As I mentioned before, it works without any problem in Visual Studio.

I realize that I miss a part. The input that contains html string is not displayed on the page. I used input with type hidden since I don't have to show it on the page.

Comment: i think [Dynamically displaying large amounts of text by partially displaying data in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689920/dynamically-displaying-large-amounts-of-text-by-partially-displaying-data-in-tex) will help

Comment: I realized that my application works fine in another IIS. Both servers are Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. One of them is virtual, which is the problematic one. I tried to find the configuration difference between servers but I cannot find a solution. Any ideas about this?

Comment: don't know about this, sorry